# Does the Hobby Lobby case apply to all corporations and all birth control?

Tags: united-states, religion

I'm concerned with the ruling in the Hobby Lobby case, and that some other workers will have the right to force corporations to provide services regardless of their deeply held religious beliefs.

**Does the ruling only apply to a couple of corporations?**

**Does it only apply to certain forms of birth control?**

Comment: I would reword your question. We don't have crystal balls. I'd you are interested in the specific decision in the Hobby Lobby case, we can answer that (it was a specific ruling that the Justices said wasn't a broad ruling). The "loophole" was caused by Congress not liking the courts ruling on a previous case involving the firing of [American Indians and peyote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_Freedom_Restoration_Act)  use. Yes, HL didn't object to all forms of birth control, only a few that they believe murder humans. If you don't want word of mouth, you need to read the ruling yourself

Comment: You can read the [decision here](http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/13pdf/13-354_olp1.pdf).

Comment: The ruling isn't about the right to force corporations to provide services based on religious beliefs, but the right of corporations (in this case closely held ones) to decline to directly pay for religiously proscribed acts.  It's a statutory right to abstain from sin, as one sees it.  I'm not sure what you means by "other workers will have the right to force corporations to provide services based on their religious beliefs."

Comment: @NL7, I have corrected the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can [read the decision here](http://www2.bloomberglaw.com/public/desktop/document/Burwell_v_Hobby_Lobby_Stores_Inc_No_13354_and_13356_US_June_30_20). The decision applies to closely-held corporations (i.e. corporations for whom the majority of shares are held by five or fewer people) whom the Supreme Court feels can demonstrate a sincere religious conviction about contraception.

Closely held corporations employ around [29 million Americans](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2014/07/07/what-is-a-closely-held-corporation-anyway-and-how-many-are-there/), so they do not constitute only a few corporations, though it is perhaps true that only a few can demonstrate sincere religious beliefs. Furthermore, closely held corporations with fewer than 50 employees are not subject to the Affordable Care Act's mandate, and some may not provide any health insurance at all.

It is not clear to what degree this ruling would apply to other religious objections, as Ruth Bader Ginsburg pointed out in her dissent.

> Would the exemption…extend to employers with religiously grounded objections to blood transfusions (Jehovah's Witnesses); antidepressants (Scientologists); medications derived from pigs, including anesthesia, intravenous fluids, and pills coated with gelatin (certain Muslims, Jews, and Hindus); and vaccinations[?]…Not much help there for the lower courts bound by today's decision.

Though Alito, writing for the majority, said that this decision does not require that all employee coverage mandates fail when they conflict with religious beliefs, without more precedent, we do not yet know what other coverage mandates could fail given a conflict.

Comment: Another thing to mention is while there are a lot of closely held corporations many aren't big enough to even be subjected to Obamacare regulation.

Comment: @Ryathal that is a point, though unfortunately I don't know how many closely held corporations are of that size.